# Alternative to brace initialization in g++ 4.4

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, list-initialization

I want to initialize this vector-of-vector-of-strings as follows, compiling with g++ 4.4.7 (*due to Operations policy, I can't use a more recent version.*)

```
vector<vector<string>> phs2tm_vec {
    { "manager_n",  "manager_a",  "manager_e", "manager_p" },
    { "manager_na", "manager_ne", "manager_np" },
    { "manager_ccx" },
    { "manager_icx" }
};
```

Compiling with `g++ -std=gnu++0x`, it fails as follows:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:271: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, const _Alloc&) [with _Tp = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >]

[additional candidates not listed ...]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13400819/522385) suggests that my syntax is correct but that g++ 4.4 doesn't correctly or fully support what I'm trying to do.

What would be a simple fall-back method to accomplish this vector-of-vector initialization?

Comment: What about `boost::assign`'s [`list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of)?

Comment: Tried `vector<string> vvs = list_of( "a")( "b")( "C").to_adapter();` and got error: `'class std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >' has no member named 'push'`

Comment: A vector is a container, not a container adapter.

Comment: "no matching function for call" is *not* a linker error. That's a simple compiler error.

Comment: Removing `.to_adaptor()` compiles; can't work out nesting: `vector< vector< string >> vvs = (list_of(list_of ( "a") ( "b") ( "C") ),list_of ( "d") ( "e"));` (and others)

Comment: Nesting can be done by using explicit template arguments, not sure if there's another solution: `list_of<vector<string> >(list_of("a", "b"))(list_of("c", "d");`

Comment: @DyP, you have mismatched parens and I can't figure out what it should be.

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is the code that actually compiles: `std::vector<std::vector<int> > vvi = list_of<std::vector<int> >(list_of(1)(2))(list_of(3)(4));`

Comment: @DyP: Perfect! 
`vector< vector< string >> vvs =
        list_of< vector< string >>
        (list_of("a")("b"))
        (list_of("c")("d"));`

Do you want to enter that as an answer to the q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dyp for suggesting this Boost solution:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
using boost::assign::list_of;

vector< vector< string >> phs2tm_vec =
    list_of< vector< string >>
    ( list_of ("manager_n")   ("manager_a")   ("manager_e")  ("manager_p") )
    ( list_of ("manager_na")  ("manager_ne")  ("manager_np") )
    ( list_of ("manager_ccx") )
    ( list_of ("manager_icx") );
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but here goes

```
vector<vector<string> > phs2tm_vec;

{
  const char *data[4][4] = {
    { "manager_n",  "manager_a",  "manager_e", "manager_p" },
    { "manager_na", "manager_ne", "manager_np" },
    { "manager_ccx" },
    { "manager_icx" }
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); ++i) {
    vector<string> row;
    for(size_t j=0; j<sizeof(data[0])/sizeof(data[0][0]); ++j) {
      if(!data[i][j]) break;      // end of row
      row.push_back(data[i][j]);
    }
    phs2tm_vec.push_back(row);
  }
}
```

To see it in action, [go here](http://codepad.org/VFKrjznu).

Comment: Are the uninitialized values in the second, third, and fourth rows guaranteed to be NULL / 0 ?